# Get the server name or ip address in C# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Get the server name and ip address in C# 2010:

I have software on your **local network.**
There is only one server in the network.
This software may be installed on many local area network. And make use of it.
I want to install and run in any location; Automatically detect the server computer on the local network. How?
I do not have the server's IP and computer name. And I want them to get a special code.
The server is the computer name and IP address. On the client computer, the server will recognize. And return the IP address or name.

I want to get the IP address of the server. The following code comes from:

```
public static void DoGetHostEntry(string hostname)
{

    IPHostEntry host;

    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

    MessageBox.Show("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:"+ hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("    {0}"+ ip.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code must know the name of the server computer.
**How can I get the name of the server computer?** or get the ip server?

Comment: Also, you have software on my local network?  I don't think so.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables LOL.. love the name...

Comment: I knew. I ask again because it was not the right answer.
Why not give the obvious answer. Only negative is it!

Comment: @HamidRezaMollaebrahimi - if the answer was not correct, edit your question so that it more clear.  Once your question is edited, it will be bumped up to the top of the active list.  Reposting your question is not the appropriate thing to do on SO.

Comment: What language can I say?
There is a local area network. In this network there is a server computer.;;;;
How do the other computers get the server IP? While I do not have the name of the server computer.;;;;
Or better to say:
How do I get the client computer default gateway address. In IP version 4?

Answer (score 0):

If I guess what you ask correctly then what you need is a mechanism of so-called broadcast lookup. This mechanism allows you to send a request to all the LAN nodes and any node that receives such a request can answer it. This approach will require you to implement the IP broadcast server functionality so that your server receives and answers such a request.

Start reading here:
http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharp-network/IP-Multicasting/What-Is-Broadcasting/

Examples here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21398/Broadcasting-Using-Socket-Oriented-Approach